# CPU Handling with Delayed Work

Tags: linux-kernel, cpu, scheduling

Hey so I'm looking at this function in the [kernel source code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/workqueue.h#L483). I'm trying to figure out how Linux handles the situation where a task cannot be scheduled on the local CPU.

```
/**
* queue_delayed_work - queue work on a workqueue after delay
* @wq: workqueue to use
* @dwork: delayable work to queue
* @delay: number of jiffies to wait before queueing
*
* Equivalent to queue_delayed_work_on() but tries to use the local CPU.
*/
static inline bool queue_delayed_work(struct workqueue_struct *wq,
                                      struct delayed_work *dwork,
                                      unsigned long delay)
{
        return queue_delayed_work_on(WORK_CPU_UNBOUND, wq, dwork, delay);
}
```

And here is [`queue_delayed_work_on`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/workqueue.c#L1512):

```
bool queue_delayed_work_on(int cpu, struct workqueue_struct *wq,
                           struct delayed_work *dwork, unsigned long delay)
{
        struct work_struct *work = &dwork->work;
        bool ret = false;
        unsigned long flags;

        /* read the comment in __queue_work() */
        local_irq_save(flags);

        if (!test_and_set_bit(WORK_STRUCT_PENDING_BIT, work_data_bits(work))) {
                __queue_delayed_work(cpu, wq, dwork, delay);
                ret = true;
        }

        local_irq_restore(flags);
        return ret;
}
```

Say if you have 4 CPUs and it can't schedule a task on CPU 1, which one does it choose and where in the source code is this handled? I've been looking for a while and can't find it. Even if you don't understand how it works I'd really appreciate a link to where the magic happens.

Comment: @dhag thanks, wasn't sure if I was allowed to post source code from Linux.

Comment: Why do not read documentation on workqueues: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/workqueue.txt?

Comment: @Tsyvarev It doesn't give quite enough detail, I need to be able to see the code that handles that transaction but can't seem to find it

Comment: Then see `__queue_delayed_work` and `__queue_work` functions' source code, mentioned in `queue_delayed_work_on`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see, `queue_delayed_work` will set `cpu` argument to `WORK_CPU_UNBOUND`. This value is defined to be bigger than the actual number of CPUs supported by the kernel. This value is passed to `__queue_delayed_work` that, if `delay` is non zero, will use timers (using `add_timer` function to fire a callback function `delayed_work_timer_fn` after specified time (this callback function is defined at work queue initialization). All this callback function does is to call `__queue_work`, still passing `WORK_CPU_UNBOUND` as `cpu` argument. So the whole "magic" is happening there.

This function will check if the `cpu` argument is set to `WORK_CPU_UNBOUND` and choose cpu to be the current processor:

```
if (req_cpu == WORK_CPU_UNBOUND)
    cpu = raw_smp_processor_id()
```

So the work will be executed on the processor which handles the timer interrupt set before. Now I didn't study the timer code but IIRC from LDD3 book, timer interrupts will be handled by the CPU they were registered on (unless this CPU will be disabled in the meantime, of course, in which case the timer IRQ will be moved to other CPU) but that book is old some this may not be true any more.

There is another hint in the kernel code that should prove what I wrote - see the comments of `queue_work` function that says: *"We queue the work to the CPU on which it was submitted, but if the CPU dies it can be processed by another CPU"*. This function also uses `WORK_CPU_UNBOUND` as a cpu argument.

### Timer migration details

As stated before, if some processor goes down, it can no longer handle IRQs, thus it wont be able to handle timers that it has registered. Because of that, kernel will migrate all pending timers to other CPUs when CPU is going offline. This task is done by `migrate_timers()` function which is run by `timer_cpu_notify` that in turn is a callback registered as `cpu_notifier`.

`migrate_timers` is run when cpu state is changed to `CPU_DEAD` or `CPU_DEAD_FROZEN`. This state is set inside of `_cpu_down` function by calling:

```
cpu_notify_nofail(CPU_DEAD | mod, hcpu);
```

It is called after `__cpu_die(cpu)` which ensures the CPU we were disabling is no longer working so we can be sure this code runs on some other CPU. `migrate_timers` will reassign all timers to the CPU its running on.

So where is the decision on which CPU should takeover timers done? One could say that it's done by scheduler:

1. If you call `cpu_down` on different CPU than the one you want to disable, then this is the CPU that will takeover.
2. If you call `cpu_down` on the CPU that is going to be disabled, it will schedule itself out in `__cpu_die` and the rest of the code will then be rescheduled on some other CPU.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't clear enough.

"We queue the work to the CPU on which it was submitted, but if the CPU dies **it can be processed by another CPU** " - How does it pick that other CPU? Assuming the local CPU isn't available, how is a new one chosen?

Comment: @IsaacGS: I've added some information about this process to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but take a look at the [Scheduler](https://lwn.net/Kernel/Index/#Scheduler) Section at LWN.